# Texture analysis methods modern survey paper

Tags: reference-request, image-processing

I want to study the methods of analyzing textured images. So i searched google scholor but only found very old papers

1. statistical and structural approaches to texture 1979 haralick
2. Image Texture Analysis Techniques - A Survey (1980)
3. Texture analysis — a survey  July 1980
4. Texture Analysis Methods – A Review 1998

Does anyone know of a more recent survey paper ?

Comment: Well, I don't know one, but a general advice in such a situation is, to look for more recent papers which cite the ones you found and work your ways forward in time.